# Check a string in Smarty

Tags: smarty, codeigniter-2, php-5.3, smarty3, smarty2

I have a problem with smarty framework, so I need to verify if an image name starts with 'http':
I try this code:

```
{foreach from=$video->result() item=v}

            {if substr($v->image,0,4) eq 'http'}
                <img src="{$v->image}" alt="">
            {else}
                <img src="{$IMG_URL}videos/images/{$v->date|date_format:'%Y'}/{$v->date|date_format:'%m'}/{$v->image}" alt="">
            {/if}

{/foreach}
```

Help me please..Exists another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work fine. Probably your data is not set properly.

Consider the following testing code:

PHP file:

```
class V {

    public $image = 'http://rwewreuiuiwre';
}
$smarty->assign('v', new V());
```

Template file:

```
{if substr($v->image,0,4) eq 'http'}
http
{else}
non http
{/if}
```

It works fine. If you change $image to hxttp you get `non http` message